# Setting String values of the Y-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to re-arrange the Yaxis values.
I've read several posts on here, but Im not able to work.

I want the top of the Y-axis to show (++, +, 0, -) in that order, starting with top. I've tried to invert it, but that doesnt help. Any help would be appreciated!

```
x = ['Subaru Forester', 'Honda CRV', 'Toyota Rav4', 'Nissan Rogue', 'Mazda CX-5', 'Kia 
Sportage', 'Ford Escape', 'Volkswagen Tiguan Limited','Volkswagen Tiguan', 'Mitsubishi 
Outlander', 'Chevrolet Equinox', 'Hyundai Tucson','GMC Terrain','Jeep Cherokee','Jeep 
Compass']
y = ['+', '++','++','+','++','+','0','0','+','0','0','0','0','-','0']


BIGGER_SIZE = 40

plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=BIGGER_SIZE)
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=BIGGER_SIZE)
#plt.rc('label', labelsize=BIGGER_SIZE)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (90, 40)
plt.title('title name')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('Make')
plt.ylabel('Owner Recomendation')
#axes = plt.gca()


plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between the y-axis values and the labels? What does the height of the bar graph represent?

Answer (score 0):

When using categorical plotting (i.e. plotting strings rather than floats or integers), they will show up on the axes in the order they are first plotted. So in this case, the first value in the `y` list is `+`, so that shows up first at the bottom, the second value is `++`, so that shows up second, and so on.

There is a way around this: we can create a "dummy" plot, in the order we want the y-axis values to show up, to fix them on the axis, and then remove that plot so you don't see it. If you add these two lines of code just before your `plt.bar(x,y)` line, it should work fine.

```
dummy, = plt.plot(['Subaru Forester']*4, ['-', '0', '+', '++'], 'ko')
dummy.remove()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and taking the time to help me. Works like a charm!